# How do I link a tkinter splash screen to a customtkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, subprocess, customtkinter

In my project files I have a splash screen that destroys itself after five seconds. When the splashscreen is destroyed I want a customtkinter window to open but the window is opening before the splashscreen. I want to be able to use this splash screen to greet users when the file is executed.

Here is my code:

```
#imports
from tkinter import *
import caspermain as cn
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

#window
splash_root = Tk()

# splash window properties
spl_height = 500
spl_width = 500
spl_x = (splash_root.winfo_screenwidth()//2)-(spl_width//2)
spl_y = (splash_root.winfo_screenheight()//2)-(spl_height//2)
splash_root.geometry('{}x{}+{}+{}'.format(spl_width, spl_height, spl_x, spl_y))
splash_root.configure(bg='#15202B') # window bg
splash_root.overrideredirect(True) # turns title bar

gifImage = r'ghostsplashscreen.gif' # come back to this if it doesnt work
openImage = Image.open(gifImage)
frames = openImage.n_frames
ImageObject = [PhotoImage(file=gifImage, format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]
count = 0
showAnimation = None
def animation(count):
    global showAnimation
    newImage = ImageObject[count]
    gif_Label.configure(image=newImage)
    count +=1
    if count == frames:
        count = 0
    showAnimation = splash_root.after(500, lambda: animation(count))

gif_Label = Label(splash_root, bg='#D4CEC3') # change the background for the splash screen
splash_root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor')
gif_Label.place(x=0, y=0, width=500, height=500)
animation(count)

def main_window():
    splash_root.destroy()
    cn.main_window()
    
    
splash_root.after(5000, main_window)

mainloop()
```

I am still trying to find better ways to link the two python files together, but every solution I have researched into thus far has provided no results to my problem. If there is a way to have both tkinter and a customtkinter window on the same py file that would also solve my issue. I am new to python and I don't have a mentor and I am new to coding so I don't know who else I can go to for help with this problem.

Tried:

**os,
subprocess,
importing main window file (caspermain.py) into splash file (main.py),
chatgpt**

None of the following above has provided a surefire way to make the customtkinter py file execute after the regular tkinter window (splashscreen) is done with its animation sequence.

Comment: You are writing this in a less than optimal way. I would first define your import as `import tkinter as tk` This will help keep things well defined in your code and prevent some common issues. Next That `mainloop()` at the end should specifically target the defined root in this case `slash_root.mainloop()`. That said you do not want to do it like this since your next call is the destroy of the main root window. This is likely where you issue is and I would instead use only one root window and then build your splash screen using `toplevel()` window instead.

Comment: You also need to provide the `caspermain.py` code. More specifically you need to provided a minimum verifiable example where you can demonstrate this problem with as little code as needed.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try what you said!